# How to save screenshots with its exif data edited by user (in Flex 4.6 application)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video-streaming, exif, video-player

I need to develop a web application which captures snapshot of live stream video in Spark VideoPlayer and then ask for user input regarding EXIF tags then save the image along with its EXIF data to the local drive. An early response will be highly appreciated. Thanks

I have used the following code, but so far have not been succeed in editing the exif data into image header

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     width="400" height="410" title="Snapshot"
     close="titlewindow1_closeHandler(event)"
     windowMoveStart="basewidget1_widgetConfigLoadedHandler(event)"
     >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[           
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
        import mx.graphics.codec.*;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        [Bindable]
        public var saveName:String ="";


        protected function basewidget1_widgetConfigLoadedHandler(event:Event):void
        {

        }   

        protected function titlewindow1_closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

        }           
        protected function SaveImg_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
          var d:Date = new Date();

              var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(pic1, 300, new PNGEncoder());
              var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
              file.save(image.data, saveName+" "+d.date+ "-"+d.month +"-"+d.fullYear + d.hours+ d.minutes + d.seconds);
        }  
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>



</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Image id="pic1" x="41" y="34" width="100%" height="300"/>
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="30" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:TextInput id="Title" x="35" width="60" prompt="Title"/>
        <mx:DateField id="DateTaken" x="78" width="137"/>
        <s:TextInput id="info" width="80" prompt="Info"/>
        <s:TextInput id="User Comments" width="80" prompt="User Comments" restrict="0-9,."/>
    </s:HGroup>

</s:VGroup>
<s:HGroup x="3" y="348" width="100%" height="30" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Button id="SaveImg0" label="Save" click="SaveImg_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Comment: This is the code I have found so far to take image and save it but it does not save the info given by the user.

Comment: If your question is about coding, particularly code you have written yourself, then this is the place for you. If your question is about how to use a certain application or how to save a screenshot using a GUI, then this is off topic and I suggest that you close this question and ask elsewhere. The stackexchange network (http://stackexchange.com) contain many sites that, in such case, might be more appropriate.

Comment: My query is about coding

Comment: @Kkuiila I have not found any solution yet, can you suggest me one.

Comment: No, sorry. I can't. I think you still need to improve yor question. You haven't shown where in the code you have problems for example. You are expected to debug the code yourself and then highlight where you have problems. It seems to me like you are using a gui to generate that code without understanding the code itself and what the code does.